# Encountering SQL30000N Execution failed because of a Distributed Protocol Error

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have Successfully cataloged remote iseries OS/400 DB2 on db2 9.1 ESE.
I am able to connect to database successfully as well but when i run below query or any other query i get following error:-

**Query:** 
select 1 from sysibm.tables

**Error:**

Encountering **SQL30000N**  Execution failed because of a Distributed Protocol Error that will
not affect the successful execution of subsequent commands or SQL statements:
Reason Code **"0x1254"("0200")**.  SQLSTATE=58008

Pls let me know where i am making mistake..?

Comment: What do you mean by "successfully cataloged"? Did you install DB2 Connect?

Comment: I think DB2 Connect is not required if you have DB2 Enterprise Server Edition.

Comment: I have cataloged remote OS400 DB on db2 ESE 9.1 and DB2 ESE 9.1 already comes with db2 connect Software, so no need to install DB2 Connect. I have successfully connected to remote os400 DB but not able to execute any query

Comment: The fact that the DB2 Connect license in included with your product doesn't mean you don't need to configure it properly. Do you see anything in the gateway diagnostic log when the error occurs?

Comment: What "OS/400" version is running? (If it's too old, numerous problems might exist.) What driver are you using? DB2 Connect shouldn't be required; at least, I don't have it. I do, however, have and use the IBM unixODBC driver, used primarily with IBM Data Studio.

Comment: Server version : OS 400 5.3.0